# RUNNING TOTAL with ARRAYFORMULA that can SUM and SUBTRACT if cell values changes

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative total in a column. It needs to sum or subtract if the value of (A) cell is set to buy or sell. here is an example:

| A (task) | B (qtty) | C (total) | calculation explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| buy | 10 | 10 | sum 10 |
| buy | 10 | 20 | sum 10 |
| sell | 5 | 15 | subtract 5 |
| buy | 20 | 35 | sum 20 |
| sell | 10 | 25 | subtract 10 |

I´m using the folowing formula:

```
={"Total", ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),IF(A2:A="buy",SUMIF(ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B),B2:B), "NEED CODE FOR SELL" ),))}
```

Is there another way to do the calc?

I don't want to use negative values to subtract, because the values are used in other formulas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
=SCAN(0,A2:A,LAMBDA(ac,cv,if(cv="",,ac + ifs(cv="buy",OFFSET(cv,,1),cv="sell",-OFFSET(cv,,1)))))
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SCAN`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(SCAN(,A2:A&B2:B,LAMBDA(tot,cur,tot+REGEXEXTRACT(cur,"\d+")*IF(REGEXMATCH(cur,"(?i)buy"),1,-1)))))
```

Or:

```
=SCAN(,B2:B,LAMBDA(tot,cur,IF(cur,tot+IF(INDEX(A2:A,ROW(cur)-1)="buy",cur,-cur),)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to do it with Sumif:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,
sumif(row(A2:A)*if(A2:A="buy",1,9^9),"<="&row(A2:A),B2:B)-
sumif(row(A2:A)*if(A2:A="sell",1,9^9),"<="&row(A2:A),B2:B)))
```

[image]

Of course, there's no particular reason for doing it this way now that you have lambdas. I'm including it for old time's sake as I was one of the first people to use Sumif in this way.